# Can't display a .jpg picture with Picasso

Tags: android, jpeg, picasso

I can't get to display a .jpg image hosted on a website (http://tnm5.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/11juin.jpg)

I did several tests with .png files and it worked well.
here is the code used.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scrim_layout);

    String url ="http://tnm5.ma/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/11juin.jpg";
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);




}
```

I don't get any error, it just doesn't show up

Comment: imageView is visible from your side? and internet permission required in manifest

Comment: May be **image dimesions** are large, try to resize it with `resize()` function after `load()`.

Comment: paste your xml code as well.

Comment: why you're passing context to Picasso. just use `.get().` Picasso automatically take context from `get()` method

Comment: I am using picasso 2.5.2, the latest version produces some troubles with gradle

Comment: @M-Wane what's trouble with gradle ?

Comment: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0

Comment: The image is a plain vanilla baseline JPEG stream.